# Graph of $x^n+nx^{n-1}y+nx^{n-2}y^2+...+nxy^{n-1}+y^n=0$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Today, I was taught about the 'homogenous' equation of 2-degree that represents a pair of straight lines intersecting at the origin. The equation was $ax^2+2hxy+y^2=0.$

Back at home, I was 'playing' with Desmos(the online graphing calculator) and plotting the graphs of functions of the form (let me generalise it),

> $$x^n+nx^{n-1}y+nx^{n-2}y^2+...+nxy^{n-1}+y^n=0,\space \space \space n\in \mathbb{N}$$

I tried(with the help of Desmos) with 5 values for $n$, i.e. for $n=1,2,3,4,5$ and saw that

> It 'always' represents straight lines.

So, am I correct? Why or why not. How does this depend on $n$?.

Thanks, in advance for any help.

Edit-Based on a valuable comment by @Carl Schildkraut I made some changes.

Comment: At $n=2$, doesn't it represent just one line ($y=-x$)?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut I think that it will be $x^2+2xy+y^2$ for $n=2$.

Comment: so $(x+y)^2=0 \implies x+y=0$, right?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut oh yeah! Yea. The two lines coincide into one.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Thanks for your interest. I made a small edit.

Comment: [I loaded into desmos and I believe it's always a few lines, but not necessarily 1 or 2](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/so7qmvlcbg)

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut:  can you report specific cases with *more* than two lines?  Can you report number of lines vs. $n$ for a bunch of $n$?

Comment: @RobertLewis I would conjecture that it is $2$ lines for all even $n>2$ (at $n=2$ there is a double root), and $3$ lines for all odd $n>1$ (at $n=1$ it is just the single line $x+y=0$). This is confirmed numerically up through $n=9$.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut:  thanks.  Would be most interested in further reports!

Comment: By fundamental theorem of algebra every homogeneous polynomial in 2 variables $x^n+a_1xy^{n-1}+\ldots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}y+a_ny^n=0$ can be written as $(x-\alpha_1 y)(x-\alpha_2 y)\ldots(x-\alpha_n y)=0$ .Each factor CAN be the equation of a line in the $xy$ plane when  $\alpha_k$ is real. Anyway if $n$ is odd then the polynomial represents at least one real line in the plane $xy$

Answer (score 4):

By plugging $y=mx$ into
$$x^n+nx^{n-1}y+nx^{n-2}y^2+\dots+nxy^{n-1}+y^n=0$$
we get
$$x^n(1+n(m+m^2+\dots+m^{n-1})+m^n)=0$$
which means that the locus is made by a number $d$ of lines through the origin $y=mx$ where $d$ is the number of distinct real solutions of the polynomial equation 
$$P(m):=1+n(m+m^2+\dots+m^{n-1})+m^n=0$$
Note that if $m$ is a solution then it has to be negative and also $1/m$ is a solution.
If $n$ is odd then $P(-1)=0$, that is one of the lines is $y=-x$. If $n$ is even then $P(-1)=1-n+1<0$ for $n>2$, and $P(0)=1>0$, hence by continuity there is a solution in the interval $(-1,0)$ and by the previous remark there is a solutions in $(-\infty,-1)$.

From dxiv's comment below, by multiplying $P$ by $m−1\not=0$ (note that $P(1)\not=0$) we obtain 
$$f(m):=m^{n+1}+(n−1)m^n−(n−1)m−1=0$$
then
$$f'(m)=(n+1)m^{n}+n(n−1)m^{n-1}−(n−1)$$
and 
$$f''(m)=(n+1)nm^{n-1}+n(n−1)^2m^{n-2}=nm^{n-2}((n+1)m+(n−1)^2)$$
Since for $n>2$, $f''$ has exactly two real solutions namely $0$ and $-(n-1)^2/(n+1)$. Then, by [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem), $f'$ has at most three real zeros and $f$ has at most four real zeroes. Since $f(m)=(m-1)P(m)$ and $P(1)\not=0$, it follows that $P$ has at most THREE distinct real solutions.

Comment: @Carl Schildkraut, RobertLewis and me have observed that the number of lines is 3 if $n$ is an odd$>1$ and is 2 if $n$ is an even$>2$. So, can you show that how many solutions the polynomial equation will have for different conditions on $n$?

Comment: @tatan Let me think about it...

Comment: FWIW multiplying by $m-1 \ne 0$ gives $\,m^{n+1}+(n-1)m^n-(n-1)m-1=0\,$.

Comment: I read through the substitution which gave rise to a polynomial equation. How does this prove that the equation always represents straight lines? Please explain.

Comment: @tatan If $(x,y)$ is a solution, $(kx,ky)$ is a solution for any $k$.

Comment: @tatan From above, if a point $(x_0,y_0)\not=(0,0)$ is on the locus and on the line $y=mx$ then $1+n(m+m^2+\dots+m^{n-1})+m^n=0$. This implies that ALL the points of the line $y=mx$ belongs to the locus.

Comment: See my edited answer. What do you think?